# C# I can't get Team Foundation Server's field list values

Tags: c#, field, tfs-workitem

I successfully connected to TFS in C# and can query information from tfs by using TFSWorkItem class.
There are several test stands in my company, where we are testing our system. So, when we are finding a bug we write this information in tfs and on which test stand it was found. There is "Found On Stand" field in TFS. So, how can I get the list of these test stands? I suppose, I should use not a tfsWorkItems class. The only way, I can get all workitems from tfs, and get stand name by field name, from tfsworkitem class. But it is not good.  How can I find out where test stand's list is stored? Or which class should I use? 
[image]